# Olimex EKG-EMG arduino shield (linux monitor)

Tags: arduino, ekg

Recently I have started using an EKG/EMG arduino's shield from Olimex: [EKG/EMG Shield](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Duino/Shields/SHIELD-EKG-EMG/)

The documentation have references for Electric Guru software only, but this software is closed source and it doesn't works in Linux.

I searched in internet but I have not success results.

My question is: is there another monitor software or any example for plot the captured signals by the electrodes?

Answer (score 1):

not as I would know.

whowever, looking at the source code that is turning at the arduino microcontroller the protocol is fairly simple. I mean this one: https://www.olimex.com/Products/Duino/Shields/SHIELD-EKG-EMG/resources/ShieldEkgEmgDemo.zip

if i remember well, it sends out the packets: the rotating packet counter [count], and array of measurements [data] separated by 0xa5 0x5a bytes.

```
struct Olimexino328_packet
{
  uint8_t   sync0;      // = 0xa5
  uint8_t   sync1;      // = 0x5a
  uint8_t   version;    // = 2 (packet version)
  uint8_t   count;      // packet counter. Increases by 1 each packet.
  uint16_t  data[6];    // 10-bit sample (= 0 - 1023) in big endian (Motorola) format.
  uint8_t   switches;   // State of PD5 to PD2, in bits 3 to 0.
};
```

some time ago, I have written a small python script for interfacing that (which is not finished yet), where you could do whatever you wish with the data - plotting, cool calculations and machine learning, etc.  If you are interested, I could search for, and send you the source code... best after march 15.

however so far for some reason it starts receiving the data only after starting the  Electric Guru once.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps you a bit, im also trying to build an open source component

http://bakerdh.wordpress.com/2013/01/31/a-first-look-at-the-olimex-eeg-smt/

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a Python package to capture data from the [Olimex EKG/EMG shield](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Duino/Shields/SHIELD-EKG-EMG/).

https://pypi.python.org/pypi

I am currently working towards a pre-alpha release.

**Update**:

I just pushed up an alpha version of the package I mentioned before to PyPI.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/olimex-ekg-emg/0.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I have a github repo that contains a Processing 3 visualizer that might be helpful.  Processing 3 is very similar to the Arduino IDE.

https://github.com/fractalbass/ekg_field_monitor/tree/master/processing/ECG_Display

I also have a blog post that goes into some detail about what is going on in that sample program...

https://pragmaticiot.wordpress.com/2016/04/13/i-got-rhythm/

In the end, all you really need to do with the shield is just read the values on pins A0-A5.  They will contain values you can graph to get the waveforms.

Good Luck

Miles Porter
Mporter@paintedharmony.com

Answer (score 0):

Arduino IDE now has inbuilt Serial Plotter under Tools menu. Olimex provides a [good document](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Duino/AVR/OLIMEXINO-2560/resources/Olimex2560-EKG.pdf) for hooking everything up and this is their code:

```
const int analogInPin = A0;

void setup() {  
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {  
    int sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);
    Serial.println(sensorValue);
}
```